# Dice rolling program doesn't reset my score to 0 if the dice lands on a certain number

Tags: c++

I have pretty much completed my program and it runs fine, but when I'm rolling for both the player and AI and roll a 1 (bust number) it doesn't set my pot = 0. It just keeps the running number and moves on. Is there some logic here I'm not understanding? 
PS - It wouldn't let me post my entire code so I just posted part of it

```
//AI
int aiTurn(int AI) {
    //Variables
    int pot = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char choice = ' ';
    cout << "AI turn" << endl;
    //While loop until AI turn reaches 20 or score >=50
    while (count < 20 && AI < 50) {
        int rollValue = diceRoll();
        //Incrementing turn
        count++;
        //Checking for bust
        if (rollValue == 1) {
            cout << "Die Roll " << rollValue << " : BUST" << endl << endl;
            pot = 0;
            return AI;
        }
        //Else increment 
        else {
            pot += rollValue;
            cout << "Die Roll : " << rollValue << "   Pot : " << pot << endl;
            AI += rollValue;
        }
    }
    return AI;
}
```

Comment: When `rollValue` is 1 your function exits (returning `AI`). How do you observe that it doesn't set `pot` to 0?

Comment: `pot = 0;` You are setting this local variable, then immediately returning`AI`.  So what is the purpose of setting `pot` to 0?

Comment: Remove the `return AI;` below where you set `pot = 0;` It's not needed there I think.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO `(count < 20 && AI < 50)` is incorrect, for the specifications you ascribe, it should be `((count < 20) || (AI < 50))`. Please refer to the below code for further modifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int diceRoll() { return rand() % 6 + 1; }

int aiTurn(int AI) {
    int pot = 0;
    int AI_value_to_be_returned = 0;
    //char choice;
    cout << "AI turn\n";
    //While loop until AI turn reaches 20 or score >=50

    int count = 0;
    while ((count < 20) || (AI < 50)) {
        int rollValue = diceRoll();
    printf("dice roll {%d}\n", rollValue);
        //Incrementing turn

        //Checking for bust
        if (rollValue == 1) {
            cout << "Die Roll " << rollValue << " : BUST" << endl << endl;
            pot = 0;
        AI_value_to_be_returned = AI;
        cout << "Die Roll " << rollValue << " : BUST Pot Value = " << pot << endl;
        break;
        } else {
            pot += rollValue;
            cout << "Die Roll : " << rollValue << "   Pot : " << pot << endl;
            AI += rollValue;
        }
    count++;
    }
    return AI_value_to_be_returned;
}

int main() { printf("aiTurn {%d}\n", aiTurn(50)); return 0; }
```

OUTPUT:

```
AI turn
dice roll {2}
Die Roll : 2   Pot : 2
dice roll {5}
Die Roll : 5   Pot : 7
dice roll {4}
Die Roll : 4   Pot : 11
dice roll {2}
Die Roll : 2   Pot : 13
dice roll {6}
Die Roll : 6   Pot : 19
dice roll {2}
Die Roll : 2   Pot : 21
dice roll {5}
Die Roll : 5   Pot : 26
dice roll {1}
Die Roll 1 : BUST

Die Roll 1 : BUST Pot Value = 0
```